# Run testes in multiples folders in github from github actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions, cicd

In a mass resource I have, one for backend and one for front end
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN8fU.png
I can activate github actions for each merge request, run the tests on each of the examined masses, how do I do that? tried to add separate steps but it didn't work as I expected
When checking node version, installing dependencies, the command doesn't go into the folder to check, for example

> `Run cd frontend && npm install /home/runner/work/_temp/10812753-f996-45a0-b389-64a758478fc9.sh: line 1: cd: frontend: No such file or directory Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

```
jobs:
 build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [12.x]
    # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

steps:
  # Pipe Frontend
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      cd frontend && npm install
  - name: Tests
    run: |
        cd frontend
        npm test
        
  - name: Lint
    run: |
      cd frontend
      npm run lint
  # Pipe Backend    
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      cd backend; npm install
  - name: Tests
    run: |
        cd backend; npm test
  - name: Lint
    run: |
      cd backend; npm run lint
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a working directory to each step, something like:

```yaml
jobs:
 build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [12.x]
    # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

steps:
  # Pipe Frontend
  - name: Install dependencies
    working-directory: ./frontend
    run: npm install
  - name: Tests
    working-directory: ./frontend
    run: npm test
```

You find it in the docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_iddefaultsrun

Comment: I tried, but it duplicates the directory, and it keeps giving error

`'/home/runner/work/my-space/my-space/frontend'`

Comment: Which directory gets duplicated where? In which step does the error occur? What's the full error message?

Comment: This error: 
Run npm install
Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/home/runner/work/mydiretory/mydiretory/frontend'. No such file or directory

"mydiretory" is name of folder, are duplicate